# MVC: pass IEnumerable inside ViewModel into EditorForModel() template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, editorformodel

this is my very first question here, so Id greatly appreciate if I could get some helps.
Well...I have the code below where i send IEnumerable into View, the EditorForModel render the whole list to be edit just fine.

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.Requirements>
... 
<form>@Html.EditorForModel()</form>   //inside the template, I use @model App.Models.Requirements
...
```

The issue is that now I want to pass more stuff into the View, so I create ViewModel kinda like...

```
public class PersonReqModel
{
    public People Person { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Requirements> Requirements{ get; set; }
}
```

And pass the ViewModel into the View like...

```
@model App.ViewModels.PersonReqModel
... 
<form>@Html.EditorForModel()</form>
...
```

Now the EditorForModel render nothing, as expected, I tried a few things but I can't seem to past the IEnumerable Requirements into the Template.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Requirements)` ?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks this works perfectly. Too bad I can't vote up :P